# Firefox reflow plugin?

Tags: firefox

I'm wondering if there is a plugin for FIrefox around that could reformat pages vith static page layouts so it would use an area of wide monitors better. It makes me mad dometimes to have 800 px width on page where half of mi monitor's space is wasted.

Any suggestions? Thank you for help

Comment: Why don't you switch to a vertical layout for the tab bar? For example you can use TabKit addon https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/5447/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a plugin but it might be of *some* use.

The [Readability Bookmarklet](http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/), be sure to try it out different styles, fontsize & margins.

Answer (score -1):

Be cautious about doing this. Wide columns of text are not very easy to read, and a lot of the time you're better off with narrower columns and a lot of blank space to the side.